# RegEx for matching numbers from 0.00 to 50.00

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

How can I get an regex expression that allows:

0.00 to 50.00 and also comma as decimal separator so
0,00 to 50,00

I have gotten as far as ([0-5]{1})?([0-9]{1})([,][0-9]{1,2})?
but there are still situations in which it fails. I have searched on line but could not find the right answer.

ADDED:
A small change in requirements. Actually it should be from 0.01 to 50.00, and 0,01 to 50,00. (But with the answers below I think I managed to adapt the regex strings so this is also matched)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [regex for range generator here](http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/). Generated and played with it, came up with this

```
^(?:[1-4]?\d[.,]\d\d?|50[.,]00?)$
```

Added non capturing group, little modifications and `^` start / `$` end anchor. [See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UDZyf3/1).
For optional decimal part, how about this: [`^(?:[1-4]?\d(?:[.,]\d\d?)?|50(?:[.,]00?)?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/UDZyf3/2)

Comment: Close, but strings that do not specify the decimal part like "10" or "8", should be correct too. So I changed it to: ^(?:[1-4]?\d[.,]?\d?\d?|50[.,]00?)$ and that work. And thank you for the regex generator link!

Comment: @MarcW Was unclear to me :-) added a version with optional decimal part, [see here](https://regex101.com/r/UDZyf3/2).

Answer (score 1):

This regex should cover almost all cases matching numbers from `0.00` to `50.00`,

```
^(?=.)(?:(?:(?:0|[1-4]?\d)?(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)|50(?:[.,]00?)?)$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=.)` - Positive look ahead to avoid matching empty string
- `(?:` - Start of first non-grouping pattern

  - `(?:` - Start of second non-grouping pattern
  - `(?:0|[1-4]?\d)?` - This matches whole number from `0` to `49` and this whole number could be absent
  - `(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?` - Matches a comma or dot followed by one or two digits and this decimal part can be absent
  - `)` - Closing of second non-grouping pattern
- `|` - Alternation for number 50 case
- `50(?:[.,]00?)?)` - Matches `50` followed by either comma or dot followed by `0` or `00` where decimal part is optional
- `)` - Closing of first non-grouping pattern
- `$` - End of string

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jZOMCX/1/)**

**Edit:**
For discarding zero value numbers, you can just add a negative lookahead `(?!0*[.,]?0*$)` in current regex and use this regex,

```
^(?=.)(?!0*[.,]?0*$)(?:(?:(?:0|[1-4]?\d)?(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)|50(?:[.,]00?)?)$
```

**[Regex Demo rejecting zero valued numbers](https://regex101.com/r/jZOMCX/2/)**

Comment: It works perfectly. And thank you for your explanation. It helps me understanding Regex more. But a change in requirements is made and it should be a positive number. So 0 0.0/0,0  and 0.00/0,00 should fail. I have myself changed your answer to:  ^(?!(?:0|0[,.]0|0[,.]00)$)(?:[1-4]?\d[.,]?\d?\d?|50[.,]00?)$, and that seems to work (though probably can be improved).

Comment: @MarcW: If you want to reject a number having zero value, you just need one negative lookahead in my regex `(?!0*[.,]?0*$)`. [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/jZOMCX/2/)

Comment: Also, the regex you've written in above comment isn't correct as it matches numbers greater than 50. [Check this demo where `55` and `91` are matched](https://regex101.com/r/jZOMCX/3/) Looks like you've used regex from other answer but other answer doesn't match whole numbers like `45` or pure decimal numbers like `.45` which looking at your attempted regex in your post, you seem to want them matching. You can try using my regex for all your cases and let me know if any one remains unfulfilled.

Comment: Ah, yes I see! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

does this one work for you?

`(50([.,]0{1,2})?)|([0-4]?[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,2})?)`

Comment: Close! But 59,99 is approoved. Maybe something like: [0-4]?[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,2})?|50. But thanks this already helps!

Comment: you're right, may I ask what your context is? I mean, parsing as double and comparing the numerical value should be easier, right?

Comment: Some input element does not have the right internationalization properties and I try to implement a validation myself using a regex pattern. I will rethink if this is the right approach Monday! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Each data source needs a clear specification. This benefits both source and destination processing. Not having a clear specification is a fool's errand. Every source will feel at liberty to adhere to nothing.